# uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::BlogPost

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have the following in my blog_posts.rb model:

```
class BlogPost::Fetch < ActiveRecord::Base
API_URI = "http://blog.url.com/rss.xml".freeze

def class 
    posts = Rails.cache.fetch(API_URI, expires_in: 10.minutes) do
        begin 
         feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse API_URI
         feed.entries.take(2)
    rescue
        []
    end
end
    posts
end
```

end

The following in my view helper:

```
module BlogHelper
def fetch_blog_posts(entries)
posts.each do |post|
  unless exists? :guid => post.id
    create!(
      :title => post.title,
      :pubDate => post.date
    )
  end
end
end
end
```

Then in my view:

```
<% BlogPost.fetch_blog_posts(2).each do |post| %>
                    <div class="home-blog-post">
                        <div class="news-date">
                            <%= post.display_date %>
```

With this present I end up with uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::BlogPost.

What am I missing? I feel like it's something simple that I'm just not seeing.

EDIT:
I have tried the following as well:

- Added include ActiveRecord::Helpers in my model and changed the view to be BlogPost::Fetch. Same error
- Put my helper method into the model and used both BlogPost::Fetch and BlogPost in the view. Same error for both.
- Changed my model from inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base to Operator. Same error.

The only time I've gotten a different error is when I changed the model name to blog_post.rb and I get a circular error.

**Another Edit:**
I've pulled everything from the view helper as it's pointless. I'm not using a controller as it's in the CMS. So my model named fetch.rb now has the following:

```
class BlogPost::Fetch < ActiveRecord::Base
API_URI = 'http://blog.url.com/rss.xml'.freeze

def call
posts = Rails.cache.fetch(API_URI, expires_in: 10.minutes) do
  begin
    feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse API_URI
    feed.entries.take(2)
  rescue
    []
  end
end
posts
end

def fetch_blog_posts
 @posts = BlogPost::Fetch.run.result
end
end
```

Then in the view:

```
<% BlogPost.fetch_blog_posts(2).each do |post| %>
                    <div class="home-blog-post">
                        <div class="news-date">
                            <%= post.display_date %>
                        </div>
                        <%= link_to post.title, blog_post_path(post.url_name), class: 'news-title' %>
                    </div>
```

Still getting the same error.

So I tried changing my view to be:

```
<% @posts(2).each do |post| %>
                    <div class="home-blog-post">
                        <div class="news-date">
                            <%= post.display_date %>
                        </div>
                        <%= link_to post.title, blog_post_path(post.url_name), class: 'news-title' %>
                    </div>
```

In this case I end up with the error of:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_end '.freeze; @posts(2).each do |post| ^

Comment: Is `BlogPost` in your view supposed to be `BlogPost::Fetch`? And, it seems like you would need to `include` your helper in your `BlogPost::Fetch` if you expect `.fetch_blog_post` to be a method available on your model (in which case, it's not really a view helper, I suppose).

Comment: The problem is even if I move fetch_blog_posts into my model it still comes back with the same error.

Comment: Did you change `BlogPost.fetch_blog_posts` to `BlogPost::Fetch.fetch_blog_posts`?

Comment: Yeah same issue exists. Editing with other attempts.

Comment: As an aside, putting `BlogPost::Fetch.fetch_blog_posts` in your view is bad (tight coupling, etc.). In your controller, you should do something like: `@blog_posts = BlogPost::Fetch.fetch_blog_posts` and in your view something like `@blog_posts.each do`.

Comment: Yeah I'm not using a controller. That's being handled in the CMS

Answer (score 0):

Took awhile but this worked. I changed the model to be:

```
class Fetch < ActiveRecord::Base
API_URI = 'http://blog.url.com/rss.xml'.freeze

def self.fetch_blog_posts(posts)
 posts = Rails.cache.fetch(API_URI, expires_in: 10.minutes) do
  begin
    feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse API_URI
    feed.entries.take(2)
  rescue
    []
  end
end
posts
end

end
```

Then updated the view to:

```
<% Fetch.fetch_blog_posts(2).each do |post| %>
                    <div class="home-blog-post">
                        <div class="news-date">

                            <%= post.published.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %>
                        </div>
                        <%= link_to post.title, post.url, class: 'news-title' %>
```